# Routing using D'Link websmart switch

Tags: routing, switch

Can a web smart switch be used for Routing? I am using D'Link DES-1228 Web smart switch. Also what is a web smart switch used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DLink [DES-1228](http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=DES-1228P&tab=3) product info page.

From that info, routing is not a feature of that switch.  Look for a Layer 3 switch for routing.

DLink Smart Switch Description:
"Smart switches are managed switches with a limited set of features. For a price much lower than a fully managed switch, they provide a web interface to allow configuration of basic 
settings such as setting VLANS of port speeds."